# transfer function and error gain function

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, error, error-correction

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRoDRF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know the difference between those two functions , but i want to see the relation between them , i **think** that the error gain function , is given by the transfer function , and the best transfer function which is

1. stable.
2. has an error gain function equal to 1.

if this is true , how can i derive the error gain function , from transfer function ?

Comment: The stable output condition for an input of 1.0 is 0.5. Does that help at all? Regarding the rest of your question, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: @Andyaka since `E(s) = Y(s) - X(s)G(S)` , where X : is the desired output(input to  system) , and G is the error gain function , then  X(s)G(S) = X(s) .
which is equal to Y(s) , then E(s) = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let me label your circuit nodes for better understanding of your question

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffILoE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To answer your question I must first clarify some definitions:

- Error gain function: a gain k that multiplies the error e = r-y
- Transfer function: the behavior of the closed-loop system y/r

Now,

$$
y=k\cdot e
$$
$$
e=r-y
$$
$$
y=k\cdot (r-y)
$$

So, the error gain function follows as

$$
k=\frac{y}{r-y}
$$

So, you don't even need the transfer function to establish the value of k. You just need y and r.

Anyway the transfer function is

$$
TF=\frac{y}{r}=\frac{k}{k+1}
$$

So, if you're given the transfer function (note that this is just a constant for this theoretical system) you can find k as

$$
k=\frac{TF}{1-TF}
$$

Note also that, with negative feedback, in stable system conditions, and with finite k:

$$
0\leq TF<1
$$

Comment: the transfer function that i meant , that the function that you entered on it an input and give you an output , but the transfer function that you define , is the function that give it desired output `r` , and give you an output `y` , in another woed , you define the system above as transfer function  , and i want the transfer function that described by this error gain function ....

Comment: Can you be clearer? `r` is an input, not an output. Anyway the  transfer function described by the error gain function (assuming you agree that this error gain function is just `k`, otherwise I don't understand your question) is what I defined as TF.